# Netsuite: How do you edit the email preferences page?

Tags: netsuite

I am using Site Builder, and there is currently a less than ideal looking email preferences page.

The url of the page is: https://forms.netsuite.com/app/crm/marketing/campaignlistener.nl?...

Is there a way to edit it somewhere?

Comment: Is it different than the standard email preference page of website ?  -Setup > Site Builder > Set Up Web Site  and then Email tab of the site] If yes, how do you navigate to there?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to edit this directly. 
Your best option is to inspect the classes and markup used and inject css and scripts (via a tab level tag override) to fix the page.

The other option is to replace the page entirely with a page of your own creation. The problem with that is once you do that you should only allow soft-opt-out because while you can set a hard opt-out with a script you cannot change from a hard opt-out with script.

Comment: "not particularly ideal" - could be Netsuite's motto.

Comment: So, I'm not sure I follow how to do this. There are no custom css files added to the header of this page. So how do I inject a css file to be used on this page to be able to override the class styles?

Comment: in your site theme add a tag in the "Additions to Head" section. The definition of the tag can be blank.
Then in your "My Account" tab (lists - > Web Site -> Tabs) add a tag override that either lists the css in a style tag or imports it in a link tag.

Comment: Ok, so how would I know that the email preferences page is controlled by the My Account tab logic? That's the piece I was missing.

Comment: Doesn't work. The addition to head logic for the theme isn't written to the header on the email preferences page. It's only NS-specific stuff in the header.

Comment: Ugh!. That's how I normally decorate NS pages and thought I'd done this one. If you can you should de-certify this answer.

Comment: @bknights , there is any way that we can generate URL for Email Subscription Preferences Page ? Kindly reply me. I have an urgent issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain. I think what I may have done in the past was to insert some code on the My Account page that creates an iframe. Then you grab the Subscription Center link and replace it with a Suitelet URL that has the escaped Subscription Center url as a parameter and change its target to the iframe(same domain - forms.netsuite.com))

When the Suitelet opens it uses a postMessage to make the My Account let it take over and then creates another iFrame and makes the source of that iFrame the original Subscription Center iFrame. the Suitelet detects (on open) that the center is open an then because you are in the same domain you can inject CSS. When the subscription center goes away (a new onOpen function sourced from the Suitelet page) you can again use postMessage to "return" to my account.

I think this breaks in Safari but it's such a hack that I have steered away from this sort of thing and these days would tend to roll my own and manage hard opt-outs with the email from the Netsuite GUI.